# Як правильно вживати та писати жіноче ім'я "Наталія" або "Наталя"?

Tags: етимологія, власні-назви, правопис

Доволі часто у повсякденному житті ми вживаємо досить розповсюджене жіноче ім'я "Наталія", "Наталя" і навіть "Наталка". Яким вірним або точнішим буде вжиття або написання даного жіночого імені?

Почавши з Вікіпедії [отримуємо](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F):

> **Ната́ля** рідше **Ната́лія**, українська пестлива форма - **Ната́лка** — жіноче особове ім'я латинського походження, яке з'явилось в перші роки християнства. Часто побутує в українському народі.
>
> **Історія [походження]**
> Є жіночою формою до чоловічого імені **Nātālis** (лат. «рідний»). Можливий зв'язок з виразом dies natalis — «день народження, Різдво».
> Також пов'язують з natus — «народжений».
> До української мови потрапляє через церковнослов'янське та грецьке посередництво (грец. **Ναταλία**), запозичене з латинської мови.
> Довгий час українські жінки не вживали масово це ім'я. Зробив його популярним великий майстер української літератури Іван Котляревський, завдяки своїй ліричній п'єсі «Наталка Полтавка».

"Український правопис" щодо цих імен [нічого порадить не в змозі](http://www.pravopys.net/#search=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F).
СУМ-11/20 теж в нагоді не стали. Словники http://rozum.org.ua/ також не містять відповідної інформації

"Офіційний сайт Української мови" [містить](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/leksika/zapozichennja_z_greckoji_i_latinskoji_mov/5-1-0-61) досить загальну статтю "Запозичення з грецької і латинської мов", в якій зокрема таж згадується вживання та написання саме ім'я "Наталія":

> З латинської мови в українську ввійшли й деякі імена: Валерій (здоровий), Віктор (переможець), Віталій (життєвий), Вікторія (перемога), Маргарита (перлина), Марина (морська), **Наталія** (рідна).

Словник Власних імен людей [у складі Словопедії] теж [вживає](http://slovopedia.org.ua/54/53405/363916.html) основною саме форму ім'я "Наталія":

> **НАТАЛІЯ**
> **Наталія, Наталя, Наталка**
> *лат.; natalis — рідний.*
> Наталонька, Наталочка, Наталкіня, Наталюся, Наталька, Натальця, Натаїна, Натаїшса, Ната, Натуся; Тала, Талонька, Талочка, Таля, Тата, Туся, Тусенька, Тусечка.

Досить загальний ресурс "Как правильно?" дає, відповідно досить загальні поради, [на кшталт](https://kak-pravilno.net/nataliya-chi-natalya-yak-pravilno/):

> На сьогоднішній день в українській мові обидва варіанти написання вважаються вірними, але використовувати їх в офіційному письмі слід обережно.
> **Правильно**
> Наталія — цей варіант вважається основним, оскільки написання саме в такій формі найбільш розповсюджене.
> *Наталія Іванівна це наша вчителька
>
> Сьогодні Наталія дуже красива
>
> Наталія купила чудові подарунки*
> **Наталя** — ця форма імені вважається більш розмовною, але на сьогоднішній день також широко використовується в офіційній мові.
> *Наталя Петрівна це наш викладач
> Сьогодні у нашої Наталі день народження.*
> Важливо! В офіційних документах слід обов’язково використовувати той варіант, який зафіксований в паспорті людини, оскільки фактично ці дві форми в юридичному сенсі вважаються різними іменами.

Отож яким вірним або найвірогіднішим буде вжиття або написання жіночого імені "Наталія", "Наталя" або "Наталка"?

Answer (score 4):

На сайті [Моя освіта](http://moyaosvita.com.ua/osvita-2/chim-vidriznyayetsya-imya-natalya-vid-natali%D1%97/) у статті "Чим відрізняється ім’я Наталя від Наталії" пишуть:

> **Наталія** є церковним варіантом імені, тоді як **Наталя** – його просторічне вживання, яке особливо прижилося в нашій країні.

Також [Словник-довідник власних імен Л. Скрипник та Н. Дзятківської](http://timso.koippo.kr.ua/viktorina/skrypnyk-l-h-dzyatkivska-n-p-vlasni-imena-lyudej-slovnyk-dovidnyk/) містить статтю із Вашим словом:

> **НАТАЛІЯ**, **НАТАЛЯ**, **НАТАЛКА** лат.; natalis — рідний. НАТАЛОНЬКА, НАТАЛОЧКА, НАТАЛІОНЯ, НАТАЛІОСЯ, НАТАЛЬКА, НАТАЛЬЦЯ, НАТАїНА, НАТАШКА,НАТА, НАТ^СЯ; ТАЛА, ТАЛОНЬКА, ТАЛОЧКА, ТАЛЯ,ТАТА, ТАСЯ, Т^СЕНЬКА, ТАСЕЧКА.

Роблю з цього висновок, що ***правильним є вживання усіх форм:*** **Наталія, Наталя, Наталка**. Однак, за аналогією до назви твору "Наталка Полтавка" хочеться, особисто мені, використовувати саме третю форму - Наталка. Так, на мою думку, підкреслюється українськість варіанту Наталія.

Answer (score 0):

На сайті [Як правильно?](https://kak-pravilno.net/nataliya-chi-natalya-yak-pravilno/) (не офіційне джерело) пише:

> **Правильно**
>
> Наталія – цей варіант вважається основним, оскільки написання саме в
>   такій формі найбільш розповсюджене.
>
> Наталя – ця форма імені вважається більш розмовною, але на
>   сьогоднішній день також широко використовується в офіційній мові.

До речі, цікаво те, що дівчаток із першим варіантом імені в Україні набагато більше ніж з другим (див. [статистику](http://database.ukrcensus.gov.ua/dw_name/find4.asp?abc=%CD&pol=%C4%B2%C2%D7%C0%D2%CA%C0)).

Також в [ЕСУМі](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_2003/EtSlUkrM_2003.pdf) (ст. 48) пише, що Наталія, Наталя, Ната, Наталка, Наташа і навіть Тала, Таля - це одне і те ж ім'я.